# A name for Radon-Nikodym derivatives that are bound away from zero and infinity

Tags: terminology, measure-theory

Dear Mathoverflow,

I would like to know if the nomenclature of mathematics has a name for Radon-Nikodym derivatives that are bounded away from zero and infinity almost everywhere. As in for equivalent measures $\mu, \nu$, there exists constants $c,C$ such that 
$$ 0 < c \leq \frac{d\nu}{d\mu}(x) \leq C < \infty$$
for $\mu$-almost every $x$.

Such measures could be called *boundedly equivalent*. But if there already exists a name, I'd like to use it.

Another possibility is to say the measures are *correlated*. Intuitively the condition means $\mu$ and $\nu$ either both give small or large values to the same $x$. However this is word already has a lot of meaning in maths - perhaps it is best not to add more.

Also, I'm open to suggestion if someone would like to offer a better name.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Good question. I am not aware of any standard terminology, although this condition is quite natural and appears pretty often. I would rather call such measures **uniformly equivalent**. As for "correlated" - as you say, it would create wrong connotations.

Comment: The measures induce (semi-)norms $\| f\|_\nu = \int |f|d\nu$ and
$\|f\|_\mu$ which are then *equivalent* in the usual notation for
normed spaces, i.e. $c\|f\|_\mu \le \|f\|_\nu \le C\|f\|_\mu$.
Unfortunately, *equivalence* of measures is used in a different sense and therefore I would also vote for *uniform equivalence*.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Uniformly equivalent it shall be.